# Why custom converter is not called for HTTP params with generic?

Tags: java, spring, generics, converters

I have a simple controller

```
@GetMapping("/Project")
public Page<Project> getProjects(@ModelAttribute("params") SortGeneric<Sort> pageParams) {
    return service.getProjects(pageParams);
}
```

Parameter placeholder:

```
@Data
public class SortGeneric<T> {
    protected List<T> sortBy = new ArrayList<>();
    // other fields...
}
```

Sort is an enum:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor 
enum Sort {
    REVISION("revision", "number"),
    FILE_NAME("fileName", "fileName")

    public static Sort convert(String value) {
         //omitted
    }
}
```

Of course, I created and registered a converter for the enum in WebMvcConfigurer

```
public class SortConverter implements Converter<String, Sort> {
    @Override
    public Sort convert(String source) {
        return Sort.convert(source);
    }
}

public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new SortConverter());
    }
}
```

When I call the controller, sortGeneric.sortBy has **Strings** inside, not **Sort** and SortConverter is not called

I can workaround it by creating a wrapper for SortGeneric<>

```
public class Wrapper extends SortGeneric<Sort>{}
```

and receive it in the controller

```
@GetMapping("/Project")
public Page<Project> getProjects(@ModelAttribute("params") Wrapper pageParams) {
    return service.getProjects(pageParams);
}
```

Then it will work as expected, sortGeneric.sortBy contains **Sort** and the converter was called. I can not understand why the wrapper helped. Is there a way to avoid creating wrappers?